# How to create a ODBC connection using a X509 certificate?

Tags: c#, odbc, x509certificate

Maybe I'm just missing something really very basic or really have no clue how to tackle my current Problem (valid option, I neve rhad to deal with certs before).

I'm required to open an ODBC connection which uses a X509 certificate in C#. But whatever I try, I'm keep getting asked if I trust the certificate. It seems I have no clue how to build this connection string.

I know I may have to install the certificate on the machine I'm running my application (which I did and it will still be valid for a good 100years).

I really googled a lot for this and I just dont get it. All I find is how to enforce a certificate validation from the DB-Server side. This is not what I need, I want to talk to a DB - I'm the client.

So far I have the Cert in my X09Store and can retrieve it from there without a problem, but how can I use it to trust/validate the certificate in my ODBC-Connection?

This is what I have so far:

```
X509Store = new X509Store("MY", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);

//This is the X509Certificate2-Object
var cert = GetCertificate(store);

//Best would be if I can add the cert somehow in the connection string?
var conString = "DSN=MYDSN; TrustServerCertificate=yes; Encrypt=yes";

OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection();
try
{
    //This where the annoying pop up appears and asks if I trust the cert
    con.Open();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
finally
{
    con.Close();
}

storeClose();
```

I'd really really appreciate it, if someone could give me a pointer or tell me how to build the corect ConnectionString.

Cheers

Comment: because you're using a self signed it seems you need to set trustservercerfiticate to false

Comment: @BugFinder Actually the problem also persists when I set TrustServerCertificate to false.

Comment: that sucks then - because as self signed shouldnt prompt for checking if you told it not to :( im slightly out of ideas